# Warum spricht man von Alt-/Mittelhochdeutsch?

Tags: etymology

Vor Luthers Bibelübersetzung sprach jede Region ihren eigenen Dialekt, so sprach man in Sachsen Sächsisch und in Schwaben Schwäbisch. Angehörige verschiedener Volksgruppen verstanden sich kaum.
Luther wollte die Bibel jedoch nur einmal übersetzen und hat die Dialekte, die er kannte miteinander vermischt. Diese Übersetzung wurde im Großteil des Reiches verstanden und ist somit das erste hochdeutsche Schriftstück.
Jedoch werden auch Begriffe wie Althochdeutsch (Vormittelalter) und Mittelhochdeutsch (Mittelalter) verwendet. Allerdings waren diese doch kein Hochdeutsch.
Warum also spricht man von diesen beiden Begriffen?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nach bestem Gewissen:

- Hochdeutsche Sprachvarietäten gibt es schon seit der zweiten Lautverschiebung (600–700?), nicht erst seit Luther.
  Alt- und Mittelhochdeutsch bezeichnen ***mehrere*** Dialekte südlich der Benrather Linie.
- Luther bevorzugte bei seiner Übersetzung hochdeutsche Varianten, was zu deren Durchsetzung als Standard maßgeblich beitrug (in Form des Frühneuhochdeutschen).
  Also das erste **frühneuhochdeutsche** Werk.

Zu den Kommentaren:

In weiterer Folge verdrängte das Neuhochdeutsche die „katholische“ oberdeutsche Schriftsprache (im Süden), was ihr endgültig den Status *der* Dachsprache sicherte.

Im Gegensatz zum Alt- und Mittelhochdeutschen handelt es sich beim Neuhochdeutschen zunächst* nur um ***eine*** Sprachvariante. (Abgesehen von Tomate/Paradeiser, Kartoffel/Erdapfel etc.)

Hochdeutsch/Standarddeutsch

Eine Wortneuschöpfung etwa kann zwar (neu-)hochdeutsch sein, ohne Standarddeutsch zu sein. Genaugenommen ist also das Standarddeutsche (also das, was auf Universitäten verwendet wird) im (Neu-)hochdeutschen enthalten.

Duden lässt die synonyme Verwendung zu, was auch verständlich ist – ich z. B. kenne niemanden (mich eingeschlossen), der das Wort „Standarddeutsch“ benutzt.

Ein weiterer möglicher Grund, warum die beiden synonym verwendet werden, könnte sein, dass man das „hoch“ in Hochdeutsch mit dem „hoch“ in hochsprachlich assoziiert. Und das wird wiederum als „über dem“ Dialekt (der genauso gut hochdeutsch sein kann) verstanden.

---

*Das Neuhochdeutsche ist immer noch ein Kontinuum, es kann also noch einiges passieren.

Answer (score 0):

Nach meiner Ansicht sind mit Alt-/Mittelhochdeutsch alle deutschsprachigen Dialekte gemeint, die nicht Niederdeutsch sind. Es gibt nämlich auch Alt-/Mittelniederdeutsch.

Comment: "Ansicht"? Hast du Referenzen?

Comment: Das ist natürlich keine Ansichtssache. Existenz von [Altniederdeutsch](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alts%C3%A4chsische_Sprache) und [Mittelniederdeutsch](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mittelniederdeutsche_Sprache). Alle modernen deutschen Dialekte werden [Hoch- oder Niederdeutsch](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deutsche_Sprache) zugerechnet (2. Absatz). Niederländische Dialekte wurden früher zu Niederdeutsch gerechnet, aber heute nicht mehr.